# Performance analysis of linux kernel module and top output

Tags: performance, networking, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have written a kernel module for some packet processing. Packets are entering the system through a 10Gig card. All the interrupts of the card are mapped to the last 8 CPUs.

When the packet enters the module, based on some logic it pushes the packet to 1 of the 15 queues using

```
queue_work_on
```

The packet is then processed by the worker threads running on CPU (1 to 15) to which the work is queued. It appears to me from the top output, that close to 80-85% of these 15 CPUs are idle but the CPUs of these worker threads is close to 55-60 %.

How is there a mismatch between per CPU stats and the CPU utilisation of the worker threads running on these CPU?

Also, I am seeing a behavior where the per CPU utilisation is varying although the rate at which the packets are coming to the machine and to the module is same. Also the processing across all packets remain the same. How shall I analyse this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Please find below the top output as mentioned above.

```
Cpu0  :  0.0%us, 13.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  :  0.0%us, 14.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu2  :  0.0%us, 13.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu3  :  0.0%us, 13.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu4  :  0.0%us, 13.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu5  :  0.0%us, 14.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 84.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu6  :  0.0%us, 13.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu7  :  0.0%us, 14.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu8  :  0.0%us, 12.5%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu9  :  0.0%us, 12.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 85.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu10 :  0.0%us, 12.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu11 :  0.0%us, 15.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 82.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu12 :  0.0%us, 13.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu13 :  0.0%us, 14.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 83.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.9%si,  0.0%st
Cpu14 :  0.0%us, 13.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 86.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu15 :  1.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Cpu16 :  0.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 89.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  9.6%si,  0.0%st
Cpu17 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 87.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi, 12.7%si,  0.0%st
Cpu18 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  9.7%si,  0.0%st
Cpu19 :  0.0%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 68.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi, 30.4%si,  0.0%st
Cpu20 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  7.8%si,  0.0%st
Cpu21 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 91.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  8.8%si,  0.0%st
Cpu22 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 92.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  7.8%si,  0.0%st
Cpu23 :  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 73.1%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi, 26.9%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  49500248k total,  3662876k used, 45837372k free,    44612k buffers
Swap:  1566332k total,        0k used,  1566332k free,   262376k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR %CPU %MEM    TIME+  RUSER     P   TIME nDRT WCHAN     COMMAND                                                                                                     
 1451 root      20   0     0    0    0   55  0.0  21:21.77 root     12  21:21    0 worker_th [kworker/12:1]                                                                                               
20966 root      20   0     0    0    0   55  0.0   4:17.46 root      2   4:17    0 worker_th [kworker/2:2]                                                                                                
  106 root      20   0     0    0    0   54  0.0  57:44.05 root      1  57:44    0 worker_th [kworker/1:1]                                                                                                
 1450 root      20   0     0    0    0   54  0.0  19:15.19 root     13  19:15    0 worker_th [kworker/13:1]                                                                                               
22094 root      20   0     0    0    0   54  0.0   0:57.30 root      0   0:57    0 worker_th [kworker/0:0]                                                                                                
 1449 root      20   0     0    0    0   53  0.0  21:14.16 root     14  21:14    0 worker_th [kworker/14:1]                                                                                               
  100 root      20   0     0    0    0   51  0.0  20:35.85 root      7  20:35    0 worker_th [kworker/7:1]                                                                                                
  103 root      20   0     0    0    0   51  0.0  18:32.88 root      4  18:32    0 worker_th [kworker/4:1]                                                                                                
   96 root      20   0     0    0    0   50  0.0  18:25.24 root     11  18:25    0 worker_th [kworker/11:1]                                                                                               
   97 root      20   0     0    0    0   50  0.0  20:14.37 root     10  20:14    0 worker_th [kworker/10:1]                                                                                               
   98 root      20   0     0    0    0   50  0.0  20:24.93 root      9  20:24    0 worker_th [kworker/9:1]                                                                                                
  101 root      20   0     0    0    0   50  0.0  18:33.93 root      6  18:33    0 worker_th [kworker/6:1]                                                                                                
  102 root      20   0     0    0    0   50  0.0  18:40.52 root      5  18:40    0 worker_th [kworker/5:1]                                                                                                
   99 root      20   0     0    0    0   50  0.0  20:10.48 root      8  20:10    0 worker_th [kworker/8:1]                                                                                                
  104 root      20   0     0    0    0   49  0.0  17:33.27 root      3  17:33    0 worker_th [kworker/3:1]                                                                                                
 1443 root      20   0     0    0    0    2  0.0   0:33.51 root     20   0:33    0 worker_th [kworker/20:1]                                                                                               
21979 root      20   0  2276 1076  756    2  0.0   0:04.07 root     19   0:04    0 -         ./top -d 1                                                                                                   
 1440 root      20   0     0    0    0    1  0.0   0:29.94 root     23   0:29    0 worker_th [kworker/23:1]                                                                                               
 1441 root      20   0     0    0    0    1  0.0   0:29.91 root     22   0:29    0 worker_th [kworker/22:1]                                                                                               
 1444 root      20   0     0    0    0    1  0.0   0:40.17 root     19   0:40    0 worker_th [kworker/19:1]                                                                                               
 1445 root      20   0     0    0    0    1  0.0   2:12.32 root     18   2:12    0 worker_th [kworker/18:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you *know* that the worker threads are on different CPU's?  Threads have an affinity to the CPU of their creation because of the high overhead involved with cache coherency if the thread were to start on a different CPU.

Comment: edited the description to clarify. Let me know if my understanding is not correct.